# How to check if a key in a list of hash's contains a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, hash

I have an array which consists of hash's:

```
people = [{'name':'Bob','id':12}, {'name':'Sam','id':25}, ...etc]
```

Is there any easy way to check if the array people contains a hash which contains an id 16 for example?

If this can be done with another data structure, please suggest it. I'm not stubborn on using a hash. I just need to store name and id (which may expand to more fields later).

I come from a Java/C background, if that helps in your explanation.

Comment: Why both strings and symbols as keys?

Comment: You might want to store everything in a hash instead of an array. The more stuff you add the slower lookups will be with an array. A pure hash solution will have pretty much linear lookup speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
people.select { |p| p[:id] == '16' }
```

[select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) will iterate thru the array and return the results

Also, you can [detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) to only get the first match

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find),  [`Enumerable#find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) and [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) are good way to go as shown below :

```
people = [{name:'Bob',id:'12'}, {name:'Sam',id:'25'}]
p people.find{ |i| i[:id] == '12' } # to find a single and first entry which satisfies the given condtion
# => {:name=>"Bob", :id=>"12"}


people = [{name:'Bob',id:'12'}, {name:'Sam',id:'25'},{name:'Max',id:'12'}]
p people.find_all{ |i| i[:id] == '12' } # to find a multiple entries which satisfies the given condtion
# => [{:name=>"Bob", :id=>"12"}, {:name=>"Max", :id=>"12"}]

people = [{name:'Bob',id:'12'}, {name:'Sam',id:'25'},{name:'Max',id:'12'}]
p people.any? { |i| i[:id] == '12' }
# => true
```

Comment: It's `Enumerable`, not `enum`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for your edit.. :) I was on rush.. Thus in short I wrote..